# Convert 1DPointArray into 2DPointArray

Tags: vb.net, math

I started a new project which loads and saves tilesets in style of ini-datas.
The problem is now, that it loads the tiles into a 1d- list, which got copied sorted into a 1d-array.

Now I am trying to convert this sorted 1d-array into a 2d-array.

My try:

```
LoadedTiles.Sort(Function(p1, p2) (p1.Position.X.CompareTo(p2.Position.X)))
LoadedTiles.Sort(Function(p1, p2) (p1.Position.Y.CompareTo(p2.Position.Y)))
Dim currentArray(AmountTiles) As Tile
currentArray = LoadedTiles.ToArray
Dim lengthX, lengthY As Integer
Dim yAxis As Integer = currentArray(0).Position.Y
For Each p In currentArray
    If Not p.Position.Y = yAxis Then
        lengthX = (p.Position.X / p.Size.Width)
        lengthY = (currentArray(currentArray.Length - 1).Position.Y / p.Size.Width)
    Else
        lengthX = (currentArray(currentArray.Length - 1).Position.X / p.Size.Width)
        lengthY = 0
    End If
 Next
 MapTiles = New Tile(lengthX, lengthY) {}
 Dim ii As Integer
 For x = 0 To lengthX
    For y = 0 To lengthY
        MapTiles(x, y) = currentArray(ii)
        If Not ii >= currentArray.Length - 1 Then
            ii += 1
        End If
    Next
Next
```

This gives a wrong output.

See picture below:
http://www.directupload.net/file/d/3690/pz8x98jr_png.htm
Is it possible to do it right?
Thanks alot!

Answer (score 0):

The `k`-th element in a 1D array can correspond to row `i=k/N` and column `j=k%N` where `N` is the number of columns. The reverse is `k=i*N+j`

Comment: Sry, but ; do you mean with N the length of the 1d array?                 Thx mate

Comment: `N` is the number of columns. `M` is the number of rows and the 1D array is `N*M`.

Answer (score 0):

Ok guys, I got it ( =

Public Class Form1
    Dim List As New List(Of Point)
    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

```
    List.Add(New Point(180, 360))
    List.Add(New Point(180, 180))
    List.Add(New Point(180, 540))


    'Convert 1d to 2d

    Dim count As Point = countXYAxis(List, 180)
    MsgBox(count.ToString)


    Dim p(count.X - 1, List.Count - 1) As Point

    MsgBox(p.Length)

    Dim rofl As Integer
    For i = 0 To p.GetUpperBound(0)
        For j = 0 To p.GetUpperBound(1)
            p(i, j) = List(rofl)
            If Not rofl >= List.Count - 1 Then
                rofl += 1
            End If
        Next
    Next

    For Each t In p
        MsgBox(t.ToString)
    Next
End Sub

Private Function countXYAxis(ByVal pt As List(Of Point), ByVal size As Integer) As Point
    Dim bufferY As New List(Of Integer)
    Dim cP As New Point

    For Each pts In pt
        If Not bufferY.Contains(pts.Y) Then
            bufferY.Add(pts.Y)
        End If
    Next
    For i = 0 To pt.Count - 1
        If pt(i).Y = bufferY(0) Then
        Else
            cP = New Point(pt(i).X / size, bufferY.Count)
        End If
    Next

    Return cP
End Function
```

End Class